# Should a keyword be added to C# for raising events?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

Raising events in  thread-safe way (in order to avoid `NullReferenceException`) requires copying the event delegate before calling it:

```
EventHandler copy = TheEvent;
if (copy != null)
    copy(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

or using the null-conditional operator and `Volatile.Read` in C# 6 as [proposed by Jon Skeet](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/):

```
Volatile.Read(ref TheEvent)?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

(See [C# Events and Thread Safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786383/c-sharp-events-and-thread-safety) for the discussion).

This is tedious and error-prone. Would it not make sense to add a `raise` keyword to C# so that the above pattern (or an improved one chosen by the C# compiler team) would be taken care of transpararently by the compiler, e.g.

```
raise TheEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

This would be a syntactic convenience in line with `using` and `async`/`await` that would solve the confusion around the proper way of raising events in a conclusive way.

What are the downsides?

**EDIT**

Thanks to all of you for the feedback - adding another keyword is indeed a bit extreme.

However, as the "standard" way of raising events is still lacking and as many people like the `Raise()` extension method, I proposed to add it to `mscorlib` at the [Visual Studio UserVoice channel](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3796170-add-raise-extension-method-for-eventhandler-and-).

Comment: The using and async/await keywords solve much more complex problems. `using` allows you to mimic C++'s RAII style which is more than a few lines due to exceptions (basically wrap everything in a Try/Finally) and `async`/`await` is huge. My guess is that a `raise` keyword is really pretty tiny and is actually a performance hit if you know that the event will never be modified concurrently. Completely my opinion so that's why this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: It's still not threadsafe. It's only threadsafe *with regards to avoiding `NullReferenceException`*. It's still not threadsafe with regards to raising events after they've been unsubscribed from another thread, or not raising events after they've been subscribed to from another thread. The only *strictly threadsafe* way of using events is to subscribe, unsubscribe, and raise them from the same thread. In which case making a copy is unnecessary.

Comment: The CLR already defines a raise *accessor* for events.  It doesn't require a keyword, add and remove are not keywords either.  The C# team just chose to not implement it.  They don't like hiding thread-unsafe code.

Answer (score 2):

Is it really that error-prone or confusing? Even if they did add such a keyword, they'd still have to keep the old way of raising events for compatibility and you'd have to know the *right* way to raise the event. You can create an extension method like the following to do most of the work:

```
public static void Raise(this EventHandler handler, object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  if (handler != null)
  {
    handler(sender, args); 
  }
}
```

I'd rather see the compiler team work on making the impossible possible than reducing my code base by a few lines.

Comment: It is generally perceived as confusing: quoting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231525/raising-c-sharp-events-with-an-extension-method-is-it-bad *We're all familiar with the horror that is C# event declaration.*, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840715/the-proper-way-of-raising-events-in-the-net-framework *Currently "Avoid checking for null event handlers" is at the top of the answers to the post titled Hidden Features of C# and it contains severely misleading information.* etc