# Event synchronization breaking change in Visual C# 2010

Tags: events, c#-4.0

In the list of [Visual C# 2010 Breaking Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855831.aspx) there is an entry on "Event synchronization" which states that you must now create a local copy of a delegate to check for null (before calling it) in order to avoid a race condition. Wasn't this already the "best practice" pattern anyhow?

Does this change make any difference in the StackOverflow discussion on [C# Events and Thread Safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786383/c-events-and-thread-safety)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you didn't have to take a copy if you used *exactly the code they'd got there* - because it was locking on `this`. However:

- locking on `this` is a bad idea to start with
- holding a lock while you execute event handlers is generally a bad idea

So code which was already bad practice is now actively broken. Ho hum. The *normal* implementation of events (which doesn't hold a lock but *does* copy the variable) isn't changed by this.

See the [Chris Burrows blog post about event best practices](http://blogs.msdn.com/cburrows/archive/2010/03/30/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-afterward-effective-events.aspx) for more information.