# C# Custom Event is NULL

Tags: c#, winforms, events

i got a Problem here with Events,

before your write "duplicate", im going to say that i ve done it alrdy and im not that  good at programming thats why am i asking yet.

Problem is that my Event doesnt fire

debugger says :=> "OnCollision is Null"

EDIT: DEBUGGER PART

[image]

OnCollision is my Event

thanks for help :D

Thats my  EventArgs

```
public class CollisionEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Hit { get { return hit; } }
    private bool hit;

    public CollisionEventArgs(bool _hit)
    {
        this.hit = _hit;
    }
}
```

HitControl

```
public delegate void CollisionHandler(object current, CollisionEventArgs cea);
public class HitControl : Button
{
    public event CollisionHandler OnCollision;
    public bool IsHit
    {
        get { return isHit; }
        set
        {
            if (OnCollision != null)
            {
                if (this.Width > 100)
                OnCollision(this, new CollisionEventArgs(true));
            }
        }
    }
    public bool isHit;

    public HitControl()
    { }
}
```

Method

```
 private void hitControl1_OnCollision_1(object current, CollisionEventArgs cea)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("a");

    }
```

Code in Designer [Sub]

```
// 
        // hitControl1
        // 
        this.hitControl1.IsHit = false;
        this.hitControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(115, 183);
        this.hitControl1.Name = "hitControl1";
        this.hitControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(175, 23);
        this.hitControl1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.hitControl1.Text = "hitControl1";
        this.hitControl1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.hitControl1.OnCollision += new CollisionHandler(this.hitControl1_OnCollision_1);
```

Comment: You fire the event in the IsHit property but you never set the isHit backing field in the set part of the property.

Comment: @Guardian, you have the isHit variable and a property called IsHit. Normally, isHit would be private so it's not accessible outside the class, then anyone programming against the class would use the public IsHit property to set the value. In the set part of the property you would call `isHit = value;` but you never call this so isHit never changes from the initial value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `IsHit` property is set **before** the event is wired up. to safely fire events use the following syntax instead of calling directly:

```
OnCollision?.Invoke(this, new CollisionEventArgs(true));
```

The `?.` (so-called Elvis) operator first checks if the `OnCollision` is not `null` and only in that case calls the `Invoke` method, which essentially executes the event. Using `OnCollision(sender, new CollisionEventArgs(true))` directly doesn't work, because when there is no subscriber of the event, `OnCollision` is `null` and `NullReferenceException` is thrown.

In case you are using an earlier version of C# that doesn't support `?.` operator, you can do the following instead:

```
var handler = OnCollision;
if ( handler != null )
{
   handler(this, new CollisionEventArgs(true));
}
```

It is safer to store the current instance in separate variable as I demonstrated instead of using `OnCollision` directly, because it could cause problems in multi-threaded environments. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28655792/732221) answer for more info. Luckily for `?.` this does not happen, as that is already built in a thread safe manner and essentially does the same thing in the background.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: `sender` should be `this` in this case, I have replaced it in the answer. The code should go instead of the `OnCollision(this, new CollisionEventArgs(true));` line in `IsHit` setter.

Comment: On which line? You should run this in debugger and see when it actually throws

Comment: Which variable is `null` in the image?

Comment: @Guardian, could it be that the line `public delegate void CollisionHandler(object current, CollisionEventArgs cea);` is defined outside of the class that you're using it in? Looking back at my old code from VS2005 when I've declared delegates they're always defined within the class.

Comment: @HandbagCrab , handler still be null :/

Comment: But that should be OK, as we check `handler != null`

Comment: @Guardian, Probably time to go back to basics. Create a simple class that fires an event and another simple class that handles it. Then run the code to fire the event. If that fails, add the code to your question so that we can download it and try it ourselves. Your current code has more going on that we can't see so is difficult to diagnose.