# Async TCPListener produces "NullReferenceError" of EventHandler

Tags: c#, events, com+

I couldn't find anything helping on the web so I hope you guys can help me out.
I'm working on a c# tcp listener dll which I want to use in Access. In order to make this work I made the dll com+ visible and registered the dll in the registry. This all worked fine.

Just to try I simulated access using a windows form and the listener works as it should. When it comes to access tho my Event always runs into a "NullReferenceError" after calling the async statement "TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();" (No Error in Form, just in Acces!!)

This is my WorkHandler

```
public delegate void EventHandlerDelegate(string sender);

public interface myInterface
{
    void EventHandler(string sender);
}

public event EventHandlerDelegate EventHandler;

public virtual void RaiseEvent(string s)
{

   if (s != null)
   {
        if (EventHandler != null)
        {
            //Event ACCESS!
            EventHandler(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I call my Handler like this

RaiseEvent(status);

My EventHandler works fine until I call "TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();"

In my Windows Form my Handler still works after the async statement, just in Access it kinda looses the object it points to.

My Handler runs into a NullRefer

Comment: Your event riser is [not thread-safe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3668953/1997232).

Comment: If it is thread-safe I just block the event to fire if its null right? I actually need to fire the event and it should never become null