# How to inform parent control when UserControl perform method call?

Tags: c#, .net

I have MainForm on which i've loaded UserControl. This UserControl has few textboxes and save button. Once i click save, information from textboxes is saved to file. I want to inform MainForm that information is updated to it can reload.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use events.

Declare an event in your `UserControl`, for instance:

```
public event EventHandler SaveClicked;
```

then on save click, raise the event:

```
if (this.SaveClicked != null)
{
    this.SaveClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

and finally attach a handler in the main form to your event:

```
...
YourUserControl ctrl = new YourUserControl();
ctrl.SaveClicked += (sender, e) =>
{
    // Put logic of your main form here
};
```

Comment: Actually this is not a tricky part. See this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786383/c-sharp-events-and-thread-safety

Comment: @ken2k that is highly interesting - I'll delete my original comment, it now seems inaccurate to me (read this in Essential C# 3.0, Michaelis - interesting how the experts can be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You can use event - the userControl will send event to the parent - and the parent will register as event listener.