# EventHandler: What is going on in this code?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

this code that adds registers new EventHandler(s) for an event named as `NewMail` (the eventargs class is named `NewMailEventArgs`.

```
// A PUBLIC add_xxx method (xxx is the event name)
// Allows methods to register interest in the event.
public void add_NewMail(EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs> value) {
  // The loop and the call to CompareExchange is all just a fancy way
  // of adding a delegate to the event in a thread-safe way.
  EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs> prevHandler;
  EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs> newMail = this.NewMail;
  do {
     prevHandler = newMail;
     EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs> newHandler = (EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs>)Delegate.Combine(prevHandler, value);
     newMail = Interlocked.CompareExchange<EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs>>(ref this.NewMail, newHandler, prevHandler);
    }
  while(newMail != prevHandler);
}
```

(source : CLR via C#, chapter 11 Events)
What I don't understand is the do part, first we are assigning newMail to prevHandler, then newMail is changed (in CompareExchange) to newHandler? Then we are checking if newMail != prevHandler?
I am really kinda confused. Can any one help me understand what exactly is going on in here, specially in the do loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment says, it's to provide a kind of safety way to deal with events in multi-threaded environment. This is pretty tricky actually, but here's how it works:

- What does `Interlocked.CompareExchange` is : `if prevHandler == this.NewMail`, then `this.NewMail = newHandler`
- The whole operation (compare + affect) is **atomic**, i.e. **done in one time** (cannot be stopped in the middle of the operation by another thread).
- If `NewMail` is not equal to `prevHandler`, then it means **another thread already ran the same piece of code and already modified the event handler**. So we won't do anything here and we'll loop and try again, **hoping next time** there is **no other thread** that already registered an event handler (next time we'll *re-read* the event handler; the operation done by the other thread will be now taken into account).

See also this useful [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786383/c-sharp-events-and-thread-safety).