# C# raising events

Tags: c#, events

I've been working a lot with C# recently, and I've noticed that most code that raises events in my company's code is done like this:

```
EventHandler handler = Initialized;

if (handler != null)
{
    handler(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

I really don't understand why, instead, you can't do just do that:

```
if (Initialized != null)
{
    Initialized(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

EDIT:

Some food for thought, I tried doing a few tests on this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test(true);

            while(true)
            {
                t.Ev += new EventHandler(t_Ev);
                t.Ev -= new EventHandler(t_Ev);
            }
        }

        static void t_Ev(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        private readonly bool m_safe;

        public Test(bool safe)
        {
            m_safe = safe;

            Thread t = new Thread(Go);
           t.Start();
        }

        private void Go()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if(m_safe)
                {
                    RaiseSafe();
                }
                else
                {
                    RaiseUnsafe();
                }
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler Ev;

        public void RaiseUnsafe()
        {
            if(Ev != null)
            {
                Ev(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public void RaiseSafe()
        {
            EventHandler del = Ev;

            if (del != null)
            {
                del(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Unsafe version makes the program crash.

Comment: I guess you need to ask the people who wrote the original code.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first version **is an attempt to make the event thread-safe**.

See [C# Events and Thread Safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786383/c-sharp-events-and-thread-safety)

Actually, as said in the discussion, it doesn't make the event thread safe. Thus I would use the second version that is shorter instead.

EDIT: event thread-safety is really hard to implement. Look at [what it might look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148585/eventhandler-what-is-going-on-in-this-code)... If you're not actually dealing with multiple threads that register/unregister events, you shouldn't waste time with thread-safety.

Comment: heh... was trying for that, but you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

The second version is not thread-safe.

```
if (Initialized != null)
{
    Initialized(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

If the last handler unsubscribes after the `if (Initialized != null)` then you will end up with null ref exception.

Comment: Actually neither version is threadsafe, depending on your definition of threadsafe. Sure, you can avoid the null dereference, but the first version does not avoid *potentially invoking a handler that has been removed on another thread.*