# INotifyProperyChanged - why the extra assignment?

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged

When implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in its most basic form, most people seem to implement it like this::

```
public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
    if (propertyChanged != null)
    {
        propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My question is: Why the extra assignment of `var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;`? Is it just a matter of preference, or is there a good reason for it? Surely the following is just as valid?

```
public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786383/c-sharp-events-and-thread-safety

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment to a temporary variable removes the chance of a race condition between the null check and the last event subscriber, unsubscribing. See the .NET Event Guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx).

Snip:

```
    // Make a temporary copy of the event to avoid possibility of
    // a race condition if the last subscriber unsubscribes
    // immediately after the null check and before the event is raised.
    EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> handler = RaiseCustomEvent;
```

Comment: Ok, so it is a matter of thread safety. But in an MVVM app, all these calls are made from the main Dispatcher, so it's not really an issue, is it?

Comment: Not necessarily. Yes, the views will be adding/removing subscribers for their bindings on the main GUI thread. But you could have other Models, created on a non-GUI thread, that subscribe to changes on a ViewModel's property. Of course, this might not be a great design practice and perhaps those Models should receive notifications via an Event Aggregator.

Answer (score 1):

It's for multithreaded environments, where some other thread might set the event to `null` before it is executed.

By using the local variable this is prevented and the assigned delegates will still be called.

Answer (score 1):

In a multithreaded application, it is possible that (in your second example) between checking to see if `PropertyChanged != null` (let's assume it is not null) and actually calling the delegate, your thread is pre-empted by another that is unregistering the *last* event listener from the delegate. Then when the original thread resumes and calls `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));` it will now be null, and a `NullReferenceException` will be thrown.