# EventHandler<TEventArgs> thread safety in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, events, .net-4.0

Using my cusom EventArgs such as :

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SampleEvent;
```

from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx)  e.g :

```
public class HasEvent
{
// Declare an event of delegate type EventHandler of 
// MyEventArgs.

    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SampleEvent;

    public void DemoEvent(string val)
    {
    // Copy to a temporary variable to be thread-safe.
        EventHandler<MyEventArgs> temp = SampleEvent;
        if (temp != null)
            temp(this, new MyEventArgs(val));
    }
}
```

I have **2** questions:

1) 
looking at the marked code :

[image]

I don't see a reason why it should be copied to another param ( regarding threads)

since we have the `event` keyowrd , no one can touch its invocation list ( no outsider code to the class I mean)

2) If I'm not mistaken, the    `DemoEvent` function should be virtual, so it can be overridden in sub classes... (I'm sure I've seen it somewhere)

the strange thing is that resharper also won't add virtual :

so if I have this code:

[image]

it suggests me :

[image]

and when I press it  :

[image]

so again my **2** questions :

1) What is the scenario which this line  `EventHandler<MyEventArgs> temp = SampleEvent;` will solve , regarding thread safty?

2) Shouldn't the function be `virtual`? ( I'm sure I've seen this pattern with virtual)

Comment: Resharper is just one viewpoint on right and wrong. It is not an absolute

Comment: Note that there are actually two race conditions here.  This code change fixes only one of these races.  See Eric Lippert's excellent article, [Events and Races](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx) for a full explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Events and Thread Safety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786383/c-sharp-events-and-thread-safety)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> what is the scenario which this line EventHandler temp = SampleEvent; will solve , regarding thread safty?

Imagine you do this:

```
if (SampleEvent != null)
    SampleEvent(this, new MyEventArgs());
```

If another thread will detach the event handler after the if but before the invocation then you'll try to call a `null` delegate (and you'll get an exception).

> shouldn't the function be virtual ? ( im sure ive seen this pattern with virtual)

Yes, if the class is not `sealed` then you should mark that function `virtual` (it's not mandatory but it's a well accepted pattern).

**EDIT**

```
Time  Thread 1                                      Thread 2
1                                                   obj.SampleEvent += MyHandler;
2      if (SampleEvent != null)                     
3      {                                            obj.SampleEvent -= MyHandler;
4          SampleEvent(this, new MyEventArgs());
5      }
```

In this case at time 4 you'll call a `null` delegate and it'll throw a `NullReferenceException`. Now look this code:

```
Time  Thread 1                                      Thread 2
1                                                   obj.SampleEvent += MyHandler;
2      var sampleEvent = SampleEvent;
3      if (sampleEvent != null)                     
4      {                                            obj.SampleEvent -= MyHandler;
5          sampleEvent(this, new MyEventArgs());
6      }
```

Now at time 5 you call `sampleEvent` and it holds the **old** content of `SampleEvent`, in this case it won't throw any exception (but it'll call `MyHandler` even if it has been removed by the second thread).

Comment: I guess that means that some subscribers may still get an event event triggering even after they had been detached.

Comment: @apokryfos yes, it's true. A better solution should involve a custom event implementation but even in this case you may get some unwanted behavior with threads and locks). There isn't any (AFAIK) good and general solution, probably if you have to avoid these issues you have to write a long/slow custom code for both event implementation and invocation.

Comment: _If another thread will detach the event handler after the if _ ...ok .... so how did it make it thread safe if after the _if statememnt_ another thread deleted the invocation list ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir it's _thread safe_ with a very relaxed meaning. It won't crash the application (because you won't call a null delegate) but nothing more than this (as pointed by apokryfos you may get called even after you detached your handler).

Answer (score 5):

```
 if (SampleEvent != null)
    SampleEvent(this, new MyEventArgs(val));
```

This is a classic threading race.  Another thread could unsubscribe an event handler while this code runs.  Which makes the if() statement conclude that there's a subscriber but the event call fail with a NullReferenceException.  Copying the delegate object into a local variable ensures that client code changing the delegate object reference by unsubscribing an event handler won't cause a crash.  Still a problem, you'll call the event handler after it was unsubscribed, but that's an inevitable race and not necessarily fatal like the NRE and can be dealt with by the event handler, unlike the NRE.

Yes, a method like this is usually made protected virtual and named OnSampleEvent() so a derived class can alter the event raising behavior.

Comment: _Copying into a local variable_  :  I dont get it  , delegate is a reference type , so if another variable equals to this reference type , they points to the same memory location. so what do you mean ?

Comment: Delegate objects are immutable, like strings.  Adding an event handler creates a *new* object.  The temp variable has the reference to the old one.

Comment: @HansPassant  , looking at http://i.stack.imgur.com/LUAbQ.jpg  , i marked those  points which can cause trouble in multithread enviroment. if a thread gets in in line #45 , it CAN remove the invocation list , ( so where is the protection here ?) , Also , at line #47 ( middle) ,  a thread still can remove the invocation list. i'll be glad if you can answer that

Comment: A delegate object is immutable.  That means that you cannot change the invocation list.  You can only create a *new* delegate object with a modified list.  Which is what the underlying Delegate.Combine() does, it returns a new object.  Just like a string, you cannot modify its contents either.  You can only create a new string.