# Convert event declaration from C# to Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-to-vb.net

I'm currently converting a class from C# to Visual Basic 2010.

Most parts have worked fine until I came to the EventHandlers. I haven't been able to convert the following line of code into Visual Basic, neither by myself nor using a converter:

```
public event EventHandler<StringEventArgs> ServerMessage = delegate { };
```

The converters' codes only gives me the error "End of statement expected":

```
Public Event ServerMessage As EventHandler(Of StringEventArgs) = Sub() 

End Sub
```

So, does the `delegate { }` part even need to be translated to Visual Basic code?

If so, how can I convert it properly?

If not, is it enough just using the following:

```
Public Event ServerMessage As EventHandler(Of StringEventArgs)
```

?

Comment: `EventHandler(Of UserJoinedEventArgs)` should be `EventHandler(Of StringEventArgs)` (based on your original code).

Comment: @BradChristie : Whoops, you're right. Copied the wrong line of code. :)

Comment: Why are you converting C# to VB?

Comment: Because I want to use the class with my own Project and be able to modify it faster, as I understand more VB than C#. I also saw @Servy removing the C# tag before, I added it again because I thought I accidentally removed it myself. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB.NET's `RaiseEvent` checks to see whether an event has no subscribers before it actually raises the event (it won't throw an exception), so your

```
Public Event ServerMessage As EventHandler(Of StringEventArgs)
```

should work.

That is the purpose of setting the delegate equal to `delegate{ };` in C# -- to avoid having to check for `null`s when an event is raised.  Since the event always has an empty method assigned to it, it will not throw an exception.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16712799/864414