# notifying observers when collection becomes empty

Tags: c#, .net, observablecollection

I writing console application, and it has  queue collection, that used as a factory of messages.

Is there some way that collection will raise events when it becames empty.

I just don't want start doing pulling it by myself, checking it from time to time.

I thought using `ObservableCollection` but I dont see a way to implement raising events when it's becomes empty.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have it in a `while(!string.IsNullorEmpty(message))` loop? (JUST using it as an example -)

Comment: @NewAmbition How will checking whether a string is empty or null inform you as to the satus of the collection?

Comment: What is the usage pattern? I suspect you might not want to use events. What will you use the event for? In particular, is there multithreading involved?

Answer (score 5):

[`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) fires its [`CollectionChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) when the contents of the collection change. Just hook that, and in your event handler, check to see if the collection's `Count == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit from `ObservableCollectionEx` and add your own event:

```
    public class ObservableCollectionEx<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        public event EventHandler CollectionEmpty;

        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Count == 0)
            {
                var eventCopy = this.CollectionEmpty;
                if (eventCopy  != null)
                {
                    eventCopy(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }

            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your event raising is a potential race condition. Take a read of this: http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/09/understanding-c-raising-events.html

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing.

Comment: @spender The famous event race condition ;) There is just *no* answer to this problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/786455/870604. And as `ObservableCollection` is not thread safe *per definition*, then there is no point IMO to take care about threading issue.