# casting eventhandler as delegate?

Tags: c#, event-handling, eventhandler

I've seen some coders on pluralsight cast their EventHandler to a delegate before executing. Why is this a good practice? Usually I just invoke the event  without casting.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    public class Mediator
    {
        public event EventHandler<EmployeeArgs> EmployeeEventChange;

        private static readonly Mediator _Instance = new Mediator();

        private Mediator() { }

        public static Mediator GetInstance()
        {
            return _Instance;
        }

        public void OnEmployeeHandler(Employee e)
        {
            var EmployeeEventDelegate = EmployeeEventChange as EventHandler<EmployeeArgs>;
            if (EmployeeEventDelegate != null)
            {
                EmployeeEventDelegate(this, new EmployeeArgs()
                {
                    Employee = e
                });
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `EmployeeEventChange` is already of type `EventHandler<EmployeeArgs>`, so I'm not sure why you cast it.

Answer (score 2):

The cast is (imo) pointless, but the fact that it's being assigned to local variable has a value - it makes the invocation thread safe. You can ready more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/786383/1163867).

If you didn't assign your event handler to local variable and someone unsubscribed the last delegate from it between `!= null` check and invocation, you'd get an exception. By making a copy you are sure that nobody changes the list of subscribers you know about between `null` check and invocation.

Comment: It's not just an opinion to say the cast is pointless. The cast *is* pointless since the types are the exact same, and therefore it doesn't change anything. It's the same as doing this `int i = (int)5;`. The cast is probably removed by the compiler anyway.