# Use event to execute method

Tags: c#, .net, events

I have a C# class which contains the following:

```
public event Action<int> UnsupportedMessage;
```

It also has a method containing

```
if (template != null)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    if (UnsupportedMessage != null)
    {
        UnsupportedMessage(templateId);
    }
}
```

Another C# class called `HealthCheck` contains `public void MyMessage(int id)`.

What's supposed to happen is if template is null, an event should call `HealthCheck.MyMessage()`.

So many things are wrong here. `UnsupportedMessage` is always null so `UnsupportedMessage(templateId);` never gets executed. Even is I remove `if (UnsupportedMessage != null)` `UnsupportedMessage(templateId);` will throw `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`. Even if it did work, there's no reference to `HealthCheck.MyMessage()` so I don;t know how it could ever be run.

How do I create an event to do what I need?

**Update**

I tried changing to `UnsupportedMessage?.Invoke(templateId);` as mentioned in the below answer and added this in the line above it:

```
UnsupportedMessage += _handlerClass.UnsupportedMessage;
```

`_handlerClass` is initialized by the constructor contains this method:

```
public void UnsupportedMessage(int value)
{
   ...
}
```

This initially seemed to work but it seems to be getting called many more times than I expected.

Comment: You have already created the event; the question is: is anything subscribing to it? Something, somewhere, needs to say `someObject.UnsupportedMessage += // some handler here` - do you have that?

Comment: No, I don't have that.

Comment: Why don't you call directly the `HealthCheck.MyMessage()`, instead of raising the `UnsupportedMessage` event?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're simply missing the event subscription step; you'd presumably need:

```cs
objectThatIsGoingToRaiseTheEvent.UnsupportedMessage += healthCheckInstance.MyMessage;
```

which will make `UnsupportedMessage` become non-null, and make everything work. You should also change:

```cs
if (UnsupportedMessage != null)
{
    UnsupportedMessage(templateId);
}
```

to either

```cs
UnsupportedMessage?.Invoke(templateId);
```

or (on older C# versions, noting that this is semantically identical)

```cs
var handler = UnsupportedMessage;
if (handler != null) { handler(templateId); }
```

to avoid a race condition that is possible if the last event-handler unsubscribes (`-=`) between the two reads of `UnsupportedMessage` in the original version.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786383/c-sharp-events-and-thread-safety "C# Events and Thread Safety") question, the check for null gives only a false sense of security. It eliminates a race condition, but not all of them. There is still the irremediable race condition of invoking a handler that has been concurrently unsubscribed. Not invoking a handler that has previously subscribed is (probably) also possible, because the event's backing field is not volatile AFAIK.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias volatility is a red herring; in *that* kind of race, you can't really say (deterministically) what the exact order was *anyway*, without observing the side-effects; the only "fix" there would be to use a `lock` or similar *over the invoke duration*, which would be very bad re queuing etc; my point: that's not a very interesting race condition, in any reasonable scenario; the one that causes a NRE, by contrast: is very interesting

Comment: I think that both race conditions are equally interesting, because they occur together. You can only get a `NullReferenceException` if the last subscriber unsubscribes between the two statements. The counterargument (from the previously linked question) goes: *"You'd be concealing a race condition - it would be better to reveal it! That null exception helps to detect an abuse of your component."*

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks. I see what you're saying. I'm not sure where `objectThatIsGoingToRaiseTheEvent.UnsupportedMessage += healthCheckInstance.MyMessage;` would go in my code or what `objectThatIsGoingToRaiseTheEvent` is though.