# what tuples are good for?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, tuples

In C# .Net 4.0 [tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) has been introduced.

What would be the best example of how tuples can be used in a meaningful way?

Comment: Sadly the true "power" of Tuples only really shines with *full* language support -- a clean syntax and higher-order operations like decomposition. Using Tuples in a language like F# or Scala is a good bit different than using them in C#. Anonymous types can function like Records ("tuples with named slots") but have the drawback that they can't be exposed across methods; `Tuple` can be exposed as it's just "a normal type".

Comment: A good use case for tuples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967523/multi-variable-switch-statement-in-c-sharp/7967631#7967631

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are a few resources that mention the purposes of Tuples, how they can be used and what they can be used for:

[The Practical Usage of Tuples in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajoshi/archive/2011/05/22/practical-usage-of-tuple-in-c.aspx)

[Making Use of Tuples](https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/tuple-class-for-passing-multiple-related-values/)

[Using Tuples in .NET 4.0 | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017352/is-using-tuples-in-my-net-4-0-code-a-poor-design-decision)

[Tuple Support in C# | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152019/will-a-future-version-of-net-support-tuples-in-c)

[Usages and Advantages of Tuples | DotNetSpeaks](http://dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=32)

**Summary:**

*Basically, the Tuple functions as a convenient way to **NOT** make a custom class to accomplish something. It is highly flexible and could provide a variety of uses, however since it can be very generic, you should be sure to properly document its usage.*

Comment: doesnt a dynamic expando object already do that very thing in  your summary?

Comment: @Developer1010 I see that we can assign a Tuple to another Tuple as long as the order and count of types are same.