# Real world and efficient example of solving a problem in C# using Tuple class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tuples

We have been discussing Tuple and its various possible uses. In almost all cases it sounds like root of evil, it makes design worse, and generally calls for a specialized class instead of Tuple everywhere it could be used.

It is supposedly close to DB but its hard to find a use for Tuple in db persistant logic code too.

Has anyone any real world good sample of Tuple use , preferably closer to some real world domain model problem or any use actualy.

Comment: Concerning the "root of evil" bit in your question, please see also: [Is using tuples in my .NET 4.0 code a poor design decision?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017352/is-using-tuples-in-my-net-4-0-code-a-poor-design-decision)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tuple` is said to have been introduced to .NET 4 because some programming languages (let's say, for example, IronPython or F#) support tuples as a core feature of the language, and the .NET BCL team wanted to provide a uniform tuple type for such languages (for **language interoperability** reasons, I guess):

> *The BCL team decided to work with the F# team to standardize on one tuple type for the framework so that every language could benefit from them.* (in Eric Lippert's answer to the SO question, [What problem was the tuple designed to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089706/what-problem-was-the-tuple-designed-to-solve)
>   )

`Tuple` does *not* make much sense in the C# language IMHO, because C# doesn't support tuples and some associated language constructs very well; e.g. tuple "explosion": spreading a tuple over a function's parameters, or taking a function's return values (in the form of a `Tuple`) and spreading it over several local variables:

```
Tuple<int,int>  GetFoo() { … }
//     v   v
int   (a,  b) = GetFoo();  // C# doesn't support this tuple-related syntax.
```

That being said, if you're writing only C# code, you can usually find "better", more structured solutions than using `Tuple`. For example, using tuples to return more than one value from a method (such as in `GetFoo` above) is quick and convenient, but the return value doesn't have any inherent structure — you might do better with a `struct` or `class` type, if you're willing to take some additional time to define it.

Comment: "(here on SO), I've read it and found conceptually helpful for my grasping the idiosyncrasies of .NET collections in @JoelMuelle's comment to [Philippe Leybaert's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3018107/200449) to question "Is Using Tuples in my .NET 4.0 Code a Poor Design Decision?"

Answer (score 3):

There are many languages where it's legal to return multiple values (something like `return (a, b)` instead of using `ref` or `out` (these are considered another root of all evils) .) `Tuple` solves this problem.

Let's look at `int Math.DivRem(int, int, out int)`. It could be refactored in `Tuple<int, int> Math.DivRem(int, int)`. If you think that in this case instead of Tuple you should use special classes, well, for delegates the direction is the opposite: after creating hundred (tens in reality) of specialized delegates MS has created generic `Action` and `Func` and has begun using them.

(We will ignore that Tuple is a family of classes so using them is "slow". Premature optimization and all that beautiful things :-) )

I'll add that `Tuple` solves the problem of writing short code blocks here on SO :-)

Answer (score 2):

the question is very open ended but I try anyhow.

1. Tuples are great in a local context (inside methods) to shorten your algorithm, just like annonymous functions are.
2. If you use good Types (meaningfull names) `Tuple<Result, Message>` are very readable only the `Item1`, `Item2` things are not so nice
3. this comes IMHO from functional programming (just like `Func<_,_>` and `Action<_>`) and can be very nice to have at times - Tuples are used to a great extent there - look at F# there tuples are the way to give multiple function-parameters instead of making a

> function that returns a function that returns a value

for example :)

Just don't use them in your **Big Picture** (you might call this your design) but for your local implementations they are great

Answer (score 0):

You don't usually use expose them as a part of a public interface, that's not what they were meant for (at least in C#). They just come in handy when you are too lazy to write your own class used only to solve a small problem.

I've found them especially convenient with **Dictionaries**. If you have a private dictionary which uses a key consisted of two or more properties, in order for it to work you need to make sure that you use compare-by-value semantics and implement hash code properly (or provide a custom `Comparer`). A `Tuple` already does this for you.