# How can i create in a class file a local parameters class and pass the parameters and use them in form1?

Tags: c#

For example in the class file:

```
public class DoSomething
{
   public string test { get; set; }
   public string test1 { get; set; }
   public int test2 { get; set; }
   public int test3 { get; set; }
   // others
}
```

Then:

```
if (stringProgressReport[1] == "Uploading")
            {
                fileuploadpercentages = (int)Math.Round(((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100);
                fileuploadstatus = "uploading file";
            }
```

Somehow to assign fileuploadpercentage that is int to test2 or test3 and fileuploadstatus to test1 and then in form1:

```
if (request.QueryString[0] == "uploadstatus")
                {
                    switch (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus)
                    {
                        case "uploading file":
                            return "uploading";

                        case "status":
                            return Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages.ToString();

                        case "file uploaded successfully":
                            Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";
                            return "upload completed";

                        default:
                            return "upload unknown state";
                    }
```

Maybe not using switch case but somehow to make that it will return both test1 and test2 so if in the class file:

```
if (stringProgressReport[1] == "Uploading")
```

Return both test1 and test2 at the same time. Two parameters but return them whtnh it's "Uploading"

What i tried so far:

In the new form i added this:

```
public enum UploadState
{
    Uploading,
    InProgress,
    Completed,
    Unknown
}

public class UploadStatus
{
    public UploadState State { get; private set; }
    public int Progress { get; private set; }

    public UploadStatus(UploadState state)
    {
        State = state;
    }

    public UploadStatus(int progress)
    {
        Progress = progress;
        State = UploadState.InProgress;
    }
}
```

Now i have in this new form two events how do i use in the events with the UploadState class ?

The first event:

```
public static string uploadstatus = "";
        private void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video obj)
        {
            uploadstatus = obj.Status.UploadStatus;
            if (uploadstatus == "uploaded")
            {
                //fileuploadstatus = new UploadStatus("file uploaded successfully");
            }
```

The second event:

```
private void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress obj)
        {
            stringProgressReport[1] = obj.Status.ToString();
            if (stringProgressReport[1] == "Uploading")
            {

                //percentComplete = (int)Math.Round(((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100);
                //fileuploadstatus = "status";
                //fileuploadpercentages = new UploadStatus((int)Math.Round(((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100));

                //fileuploadstatus = new UploadStatus("uploading file");// + fileuploadpercentages;
            }
```

Also in form1 in all the return i'm getting errors:

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Automatic_Record.Youtube_Uploader.UploadStatus' to 'string'

```
case "uploading file":
                            return new Youtube_Uploader.UploadStatus(Youtube_Uploader.UploadState.Uploading);

                        case "status":
                            return new Youtube_Uploader.UploadStatus(Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages);

                        case "file uploaded successfully":
                            Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";
                            return new Youtube_Uploader.UploadStatus(Youtube_Uploader.UploadState.Completed);

                        default:
                            return new Youtube_Uploader.UploadStatus(Youtube_Uploader.UploadState.Unknown);
```

On each return i'm getting same error can't convert to string.

Also in this line in form1:

```
return new Youtube_Uploader.UploadStatus(Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages);
```

I'm getting the also the error:

Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Automatic_Record.Youtube_Uploader.UploadStatus' to 'Automatic_Record.Youtube_Uploader.UploadState'

Comment: maybe use a Tuple<T1, T2> to return both values?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to hold your information:

```
public enum UploadState
{
    Uploading,
    InProgress,
    Completed,
    Unknown
}

public class UploadStatus
{
    public UploadState State { get; private set; }
    public int Progress { get; private set; }

    public UploadStatus(UploadState state)
    {
        State = state;
    }

    public UploadStatus(int progress)
    {
        Progress = progress;
        State = UploadState.InProgress;
    }
}
```

You can return an instance of that class:

```
if (request.QueryString[0] == "uploadstatus")
{
    switch (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus)
    {
        case "uploading file":
            return new UploadStatus(UploadState.Uploading);

        case "status":
            return new UploadStatus(Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages);

        case "file uploaded successfully":
            Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadstatus = "";
            return new UploadStatus(UploadState.Completed);

        default:
            return new UploadStatus(UploadState.Unknown);
     }
}
```

You can then inspect the returned `UploadStatus` instance and set `test1` ans `test2` values accordingly.

Comment: Damir i added the class to my class file. But how do i make the instance/s for the int and string ? In the class file where i added your class inside this IF: if (stringProgressReport[1] == "Uploading") what do i do ?

Comment: I did inside the IF: UploadStatus uploadstat = new UploadStatus((int)Math.Round(((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100)); do i need to make two instances of the UploadStatus ?

Comment: @Danielvanwolf What you did, should be ok. Why would you need 2 instances? You could add another constructor with both string and int parameters if you need to set both values explicitly. Also, as bashis mentioned, it would be a good idea replacing the string with an enum.

Comment: Damir i updated my question just one added at the bottom the part of what i tried now. Please if you can take a look on it since it's not working yet. What i did wrong ? And after fixing that how to use enum if you could show me please ?

Comment: @DanielLip I don't see any edits in the question!? I've updated my answer to use enums instead of strings.

Comment: Damir the other side is a new form not class file. But still how do i use the UploadStatus and the UploadState classes with the two events ? And the errors i get in form1.

Comment: To fix the first error, change `public static string uploadstatus = "";` to `public static UploadStatus uploadstatus = "";`. As the error stated, you are now trying to put `UploadStatus` value into `string` variable.

Comment: @Danielvanwolf To fix the rest of the errors, make sure the types match everywhere. The compiler is giving you errors to show mismatches. I think you need to have `UploadStatus` as the return value for the methods with all the `return` statements in your snippets.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all,** it is considered a really bad practice to use string constants to describe a state of an object or a program. You should use [enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) instead.

**Secondly**, if you want to return a couple of parameters you could, depending on your needs, do it in a several ways:

1. Create a `struct` to keep them in a single object. You will have to write some lines but the resulting code will be more or less clear.
2. Return a [`Tuple<T1,T2>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This does not require a lot of writing but I personally hate remembering what `Item1` and `Item2` were intended to be. But if you still think you want to use it, [consider naming your method carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3017771/2560087).
3. [You could also return your results as `out` parameters.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) This is rarely a good decision but it really helps in a [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-like code.

Comment: Can you show me please how to do it with one single object struct ?

Comment: @Danielvanwolf it is just like @DamirArh suggested, but I would rather use `struct` instead of `class` because your piece of code likely mathes [all the rules that are generally applied to structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx)