# Return an object along with a list

Tags: c#, .net, json, list, return

In a method

1. count is calculated
2. a list is also formed

I need to return this count along with the list in c#. Any suggestions on how to return this?

Comment: If count is of list then simply return list and get count in caller. If count is not of list then you can return the list as method return type and take count as out parameter

Comment: You can also return a `Tuple<int, List<Something>>`.

Comment: You can also return anonymous type `return new{ Count = countVar, list=listVar }`

Comment: Return list & use List.Count property to check the count of the list items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should [avoid using out and ref parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/635934/3970411).**

I suggest creating a type that represents the output result.

```
public DoSomethingResult DoSomething()
{
    var result = new DoSomethingResult();
    //....
    result.Data = GenerateList();
    result.Count = CalculateCount();
    return result;
}

public class DoSomethingResult
{
    public List<YourType> Data { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

[FxCop rule for out parametes.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131.aspx)

Comment: That's a **bold** statement :)

Comment: I read the Link, we generally don't require to use them but not quite sure on the statement it _has_ to be avoided.

Comment: Using `out` and `ref` must be avoided until you have no other way or performance problems. @HariPrasad

Answer (score 0):

2 options

1. using out param for count, with return type as List
2. using a Tuple or custom Class which will contain both of your `Count` and `List`

**Sample Code:**

```
 public List<Class1> GetData(out int Count)
 { 
   //... 
    //Your Logic with returning list
 }
```

**Option2:**

```
public CustomClass DoSomething()
{
    var data = new CustomClass();
    //....
    data.Data = list;
    data.Count = list.Count();
    return data;
}
public class CustomClass
{
    public List<Class1> Data { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the out keyword in C#.

MSDN description. "Declaring an out method is useful when you want a method to return multiple values. This enables methods to return values optionally."

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) is the MSDN documentation.

Here is an example:

```
public List<YourType> SomeMethodName(out int count)
{
    //Your calculation here
}
```

Comment: Well, I think you _can_ use out but I don't think you _should_ use it. It's certainly a matter of taste and quite opinion-based, but I think out almost always creates an awful api ;)

Comment: @khlr Thanks for sharing your input. If I may ask, what is your opinion on out, and why you should not use it?

Comment: I try to avoid it because I had to deal with a lot of legacy code which extensively used out in several inappropriate situations. In my opinion it's always a pain if you call a method and need to declare another variable beforehand for the out parameter (though C# 6 [brought improvements](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/09/15/c-6-0-features-part-3-declaration-expressions.aspx) in those cases). Furthermore I think it's _cleaner_ if a method has one defined return value and not two (or even more...). I prefer returning a custom defined type in those cases as suggested by @dotctor.

Comment: @khlr I totally agree with returning a custom type for these situations.  I also read through the answer in the post given by dotctor, by John Skeet, and that was pretty interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply return a `List` and a get a `Count` in caller method. You don't really require to return both.

Still interested? multiple options.

Using `out` parameter for count.

```
public List<something> DoSomething(out int count)
{
    ....
    count = list.Count();
    return list; 
}
```

using `Tuple` as pointed in comments.

```
public Tuple<List<something>, int> DoSomething()
{
    ....
    return new Tuple<List<something>, int>(list1, count); 
}
```

Comment: Using Tuples is [not a good idea here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017352/is-using-net-4-0-tuples-in-my-c-sharp-code-a-poor-design-decision).

Comment: That's true, but just to let OP know that there is an option :-). I don't really see any valid case he needs both the parameters in the first place.