# How to sort a dictionary that contains dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dictionary that contains another dictionary as value
something like this

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<double,double>>
```

now I want to sort it by internal dictionary's value 
how can I do that??

Comment: I'm not even going to imagine why you would need such a data structure, but what are some examples of data you would be holding, and how are you trying to sort the data? Remember that a dictionary itself is not sortable.

Comment: Some values of dictionaries and on what basis you want to sort them would help.

Comment: sorry i am not expert on c#, would you suggest a way to store 3 values as one item?

Comment: @user1225072: Create a class having 3 properties. One string and other two double.

Comment: let me try and get back to u

Comment: so the property class can only hold one set of values in that case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of your comment

> sorry i am not expert on c#, would you suggest a way to store 3 values as one item?

I would suggest creating a class and sort on it like this

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string StringProperty {get;set;}
    public int FirstDoubleProperty {get;set;}
    public int SecondDoubleProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Then create a collection like this

```
List<MyClass> MyClasscol = new List<MyClass>();

MyClass mc = new MyClass();

mc.StringProperty = "User1225072";
mc.FirstDoubleProperty = 5;
mc.SecondDoubleProperty = 6;

MyClasscol.Add(mc);

mc = new MyClass();

// and So on
```

then sort like this

```
var newsortedcollection = MyClasscol.OrderBy(x => x.FirstDoubleProperty);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are now trying to figure out how to store and order a collection of objects with multiple properties, then you have a few options. [Nikhil Agrawal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16878890/117062) is a great solution but there are times when you may not need/want to create a custom class for this. For these situations (preferably when your code is private and not part of some API) then the alternatives below might be an option.

**KeyValuePairs**

Based on your requirements and your original post using dictionaries, it seems like instead of a dictionary of dictionaries (multi-tiered), you probably wanted a dictionary of keyvaluepairs (flat).

```
// using keyvaluepair
var keyValueDict = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<double, double>>();
keyValueDict.Add("string", new KeyValuePair<double, double>(5.8, 7.4));
var sortedKeyValues = keyValueDict.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Key);
```

**Tuples**

An alternative to the not so pleasant KeyValuePair is the Tuple introduced in .NET 4. The tuple is a generic class which allows you to store typed property values without creating your own custom class. It is worth noting that there are tuple implementations for up to 8 properties.

```
// using tuple
var tupleList = new List<Tuple<string, double, double>>();
tupleList.Add(new Tuple<string, double, double>("string", 5.8, 7.4));
var sortedTuples = tupleList.OrderBy(x => x.Item2);
```

There are some good SO questions about Tuples if you are interested:
[Is Using .NET 4.0 Tuples in my C# Code a Poor Design Decision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017352/is-using-tuples-in-my-net-4-0-code-a-poor-design-decision)
[Are EventArg classes needed now that we have generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311432/are-eventarg-classes-needed-now-that-we-have-generics/311614)